# How do I install Linux over Windows in the C drive without affecting other drives?

Tags: system-installation, windows

I am using Windows 10 and have been facing multiple issues with it. One of my friend recommended I use Linux as it's more secure and reliable, but I have some important data in my existing Windows 10 in other drives.

I can't afford an external hard disk to back up all the data, so I want to know how I can install Linux on only the C drive without affecting the other Windows drives where I have my data.

Is this possible, or should i format all the drives and then install Linux?

Comment: Welcome to the world of data loss! Change your mind regarding backups, at least back up the files you can't risk to lose. Installing an OS is an advanced administrative task and a mistake may lead to data loss. As a beginner you shouldn't balance on a tightrope without a net under it.

Comment: You probably have just **one** drive and multiple partitions. It seems you wan't to remove some of them (like the one currently with Windows) to put Ubuntu on it. Is easy but you'll need some skills. In any case you must have to make a backup of all your data. Maybe you could borrow a -big enough- pendrive during the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

> Linux as it's more secure and reliable

That's a fallacy. Windows can be as secure as any other operating system but it requires effort. Out of the box Linux is more secure but depending on the skills of the admin it can too be a security nightmare.

> I want to know how I can install Linux on only the C drive without affecting the other Windows drives where I have my data.

Windows -> VirtualBox -> Linux. But that is not going to help with your 1st statement: "Linux [is] more secure and reliable". You then still use Windows. If that Windows is not secured neither is the software installed in that Windows.

You can opt for the dual boot method where you have 2 operating systems and pick the one to start when starting your system. That means creating empty space in your Windows system. It also has a risk of deleting data you do no want deleted: at the installer you need to pick the empty space or it *will* erase the whole disk.

> Should I format all the drives and then install Linux?

You can but ...

> without affecting other drives?

is going to be impossible.

Your 1st step is to make a backup and verify you can restore your backup. All your important data needs to be on an external medium that can not be affected by your current machine anyways; otherwise you can not call the data "important". With a backup whatever you do to your software on your system it can be restored.

The minimum steps to guarantee you can still use your data:

1. Backup personal files
2. Install Linux as only operating system. This will delete **everything** on your system.
3. Restore the files from the backup to your "Documents", "Downloads", "Pictures"  directories in Linux.

I would advice against it though. You can not comfortably learn Linux this way. You should start with a dual boot or a virtual system. Where the virtual method is probably the best option since you can do this without messing with the partitions of the current system.

Comment: cool !!the way you answered was flawless , but just answer me one thing ,,why is it going to be impossible ??? may be there is a way or there is int

Comment: ok thats a good point u made there . dual boot  sounds cool ! May i know system Requirements and specifications for dual boot ,should i install in one of the existing hard drive by moving the data to other drives ?????

Comment: 1. well if you format your disks it will erase everything so it does affect your disks 2. dual boot: sys.reqs are the same as with a normal boot. If you have W10: Linux always requires less resources. "should i install in one of the existing hard drive by moving the data to other drives ?"  you need "unallocated space" of roughly 20Gb for the system itself + personal needs (lots of movies means lots of space. You can connect to your Windows disks with a dual boot).

Comment: Cool !! thats make sense!! Thanks for the help mate .

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) guide, or any guides about how to make a dual-boot.

> Multi-booting is the act of installing multiple operating systems on a computer, and being able to choose which one to boot. The term **dual-booting** refers to the common configuration of specifically two operating systems.

Note that considering you are new about Linux I would suggest you to use Ubuntu 18.04 ([LTS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS)). You can download it using this [link](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).

Comment: yeah i know about dual boot but i just need only one os . i mean dual boot doesn't work for me

Comment: Well I'm not sure to understand what you want to achieve so, do you want to install Linux over Windows by keeping all your data ?

Comment: yeah mate you are absolutely right and thats what i am looking for !!

Comment: Then even if you don't want to, you must backup all of your data (or at least the most important ones) and then install ubuntu without erasing the entire existing data.

Comment: Thanks for the info that was very helpful ,once i back up all the data i will follow 2 methods 
1.dual boot or 2.formatting whole windows and installing linux >>>>

Comment: Yep ! if you already saved all your data, you can even simply make a full INstall of Ubuntu, it will automatically delete and format the hard drive for you.